# LinkedIn Marketing API not returing any ads reporting data

Tags: linkedin-api

I am currently trying to fetch all the available campaigns and ads.

1. Search for adCampaigns `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search&search.test=false&count=10` returns empty `"elements": []`.
2. Querying for analytics: `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange.end.month=9&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.year=2021&dateRange.end.day=1&dateRange.end.year=2021&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.month=1&timeGranularity=DAILY&companies[0]=urn:li:organization:ORGID&fields=impressions` again return empty `"elements": []`.

The OAuth token was generated by Super Admin user and the campaigns are managed by other Media company.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the r_ads permission?

Comment: @Sprizgola yes the token was generated by using these r_organization_social,w_organization_social,rw_organization_admin,rw_ads,r_ads_reporting